# "Your request couldn't be processed" error on MacBook captive portal using Facebook manual login flow

Tags: macos, facebook, facebook-login, captiveportal

I have been working on Facebook login within captive portals. I am using the documentation on [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/).

Most devices(iOS, Android, laptop) work fine except for MacBook captive portal. After submitting the Facebook login form with username and password fields, "Your request couldn't be processed" error is being displayed. I have checked the cookies and it is supported.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to login to a captive portal _using_ Facebook? Or is this just about using Facebook login, _after_ the user has already done whatever is necessary to authenticate against the portal?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your response. I am trying to login into a captive portal using Facebook to authenticate the user. After that, I am redirecting back the user to my page and get his/her details such as email. However, MacBook captive portal does not redirect back to my page.

Comment: Not sure what “MacBook captive portal” is referring to, is that supposed to be some Apple default implementation or standard component that comes with the OS? Have you checked via the browser console, if any of the requests happening during the FB login flow, might get blocked by the portal perhaps?